# CruiseControl.Net + Ankh SVN - svn.exe not found

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, ankhsvn, ccnet-config

I am trying to configure the **CrusieControl.net with Ankh SVN**, the crusine control installation works fine and ccnet.config is configured properly, but when the process starts in background it fires the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to execute file 
[C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe].  
The file may not exist or may not be executable. 
(The system cannot find the file specified)
```

*The above path is a dummy, I can't get the ankh svn EXE installed on my machine at,
`C:\Program Files (x86)\AnkhSVN 2`

The **ccnet.config** file is as below:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
  <cb:define PublishDir="D:\ccnet\ccnet\publish"/>
  <project name="ccnet">
    <workingDirectory>D:\ccnet\ccnet\</workingDirectory>
    <artifactDirectory>D:\ccnet\ccnet\</artifactDirectory>
    <webURL>http://localhost:62584/</webURL>
    <triggers>
      <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="10"
             buildCondition="IfModificationExists"/>
    </triggers>
    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>http://server/svn/ccnet/</trunkUrl>
      <!--<autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>-->
      <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe</executable>
      <username>abc</username>
      <password>xyz</password>
      <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
    </sourcecontrol>
    <tasks>
      <msbuild>
        <executable>
          C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
        </executable>
        <projectFile>ccnet.sln</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>
          /noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Release /v:diag
        </buildArgs>
        <logger>
          C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll
        </logger>
        <timeout>600</timeout>
      </msbuild>
    </tasks>
    <labeller type="assemblyVersionLabeller">
      <major>2</major>
      <minor>0</minor>
      <incrementOnFailure>false</incrementOnFailure>
    </labeller>
    <publishers>
      <statistics />
      <xmllogger />
    </publishers>
  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

I tried `<autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>` But it tries to find the EXE in my project solution folder.

can anyone guide me for the ankh svn exe path which will be placed in **`<executable>SVN PATH</executable>`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by installing the **TortoiseSVN** with commandline tools and specify the svn.exe located in the bin directory.

so my final source control block is as follows:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>http://server/svn/ccnet/</trunkUrl>
      <executable>C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe</executable>
      <username>abc</username>
      <password>xyz</password>
      <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
</sourcecontrol>
```